# Как представить блок-схему в памяти

Tags: java, структуры-данных, коллекции, хранение-данных, блок-схема

Нужно хранить в памяти классическую **блок-схему**, для возможности ее дальнейшей обработки (возможность перехода от блока к дочернему). Как лучше всего это реализовать? Пишу это все на Java 1.8

Comment: Вообще-то блок-схема это ориентированный граф. Вы пытались найти, как представляются графы на Java?
Подозреваю, что подобные вопросы у вас будут возникать постоянно. Найдите в сети исходные тексты какого-либо компилятора, написанного на Java, и изучите его.

Comment: Ответ зависит от задач, которые планируется решать с помощью этой структуры данных. В общем случае каждый элемент блок-схемы представляет собой отдельный объект, хранящий ссылку или ссылки на подчиненные ему объекты и, при необходимости, на родителя. В зависимости от вида элемента блок-схемы объект может иметь ряд методов решающие задачи этого элемента. Например условный блок может иметь метод возрвращающий один из подчиненных элементов в зависимости от истинности заложенного в него условия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Присоединюсь к серому гоблину. 
На вскидку.

```
// Объявить общий интерфейс блоков в котором будет всё необходимое API для любого элемента
interface Block {

    public String getBlockText();
    public String setBlockText(String text);

    public boolean hasParentBlock();
    public Block getParentBlock();
    public boolean hasChildBlock();
    public Block getChildBlock();
    public boolean hasAlternativeChild();
    public Block getAlternativeChild();
}

// Создать абстрактный класс с перечислением типов блоков
public AbstractBlock implements Block {
   public final int OPERATION = 0;
   public final int DEREVATION = 1;
   // ...

   private final int blockType;
   private String blockText;
   public AbstractBlock(int blockType) {
       // Установка особенностей поведения
       // на основе типа блока
       this.blockType = blockType;
   }
   // Например
   public boolean hasAlterativeChild() {
      return blockType == DEREVATION;
   }
   // И реализация всего функционала, идентичного для всех типов блоков 
   private String text;
   @Override
   public String getBlockText() { return text; };
   @Override
   public String setBlockText(String text) { this.text = text; };
}

// Наследуем итоговые классы для каждого типа
public class OperationBlock {
    public OperationBlock() {
        super(OPERATION);
    }
    // В котором реализуем эксклюзивную для конкретного типа блока логику
}

// И наконец создаем контроллер, который эти блоки может собирать, читать, сохранять
public class BlockController {

    private List<Block> blocks;
    public BlockController() {
       blocks = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    // Управление блок-схемой
    // ...

    // Ввод-вывод
    // ...
}
```

Comment: А где именно нужно хранить ссылки на родительские и дочерние блоки? В контроллере или прописывать в абстрактном классе?

Comment: В абстрактном классе, в каждом блоке ссылки на то что сверху и снизу. Посмотрите код LinkedList для примера. Там список реализован на обертках элементов, с информацией о соседях. Похоже, но без ветвлений.